# phonegap android app rejected by google play store

Tags: android, html, css, phonegap-build

I uploaded an apk file for my app after completing the necessary formalities on the google play store. 
After few minutes i checked my account which is showing following message,

> Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy. The Alerts page has more information about how to resolve the issue.
>  If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.

I received an email saying, 'Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

> The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher.

[image: I am attaching a screen-shot of the same error message]

**Below is my config.xml file**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="in.happyfood.app" version="0.0.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"/>
<name>HappyFood</name>
<description>
    HappyFood: Happy Food Makes Happy Mood
</description>
<author email="contact@medixpress.in" href="http://happyfood.in">
    Happy Food
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />

<preference name="windows-publisher-id" value="42688C60-E010-4B6B-8F2A-F22CD6DBE15F" />
<preference name="windows-publisher-display-name" value="InnoThoughts" />


<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />
<preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
<preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />
<preference name="webviewbounce"    value="false" />

<icon src="res/icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/happy-food-logo_1_48x48.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/happy-food-logo_2_36x36.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/happy-food-logo_3_72x72.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/happy-food-logo_4_96x96.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-180.png"           gap:platform="ios"        width="180" height="180" />
<icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
```

I built the app in following steps

1. Created my html5, css3 and js files.
2. Uploaded them to build.phonegap.com.
3. Uploaded keystore file and unlocked my app by entering certificate and keystore password.
4. Finally downloaded the file from build.phonegap.com and then uploaded it to playstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue by changing the config.xml file as below:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><widget id="in.happyfood.app" version="0.0.1" android-versionCode="13" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>HappyFood</name>
    <description>
       HappyFood:Happy Food Makes Happy Mood
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Innothoughts
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~5.2.2" />
</widget>`

Just published the app as well.. thanks for the help..

Comment: It is better to have some words what exactly you have changed or what is exact issue so this answer can be helpful to others..

Answer (score 2):

You may try building your application with newer versions of PhoneGap, as mentioned by Google Play team. You will need to change:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />
```

to something like:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="5.1.1" />
```

and update the version of PhoneGap CLI installed on your development machine(s).

The older versions of PhoneGap had security vulnerabilities that are fixed in the newer versions. Building your application with newer version will make your application more secure and your application will hence be accepted on Google Play Store.

Comment: You are right, but the issue is, even if i rebuild the apk with newer version, i am still unable to rebuild the app.The 'rebuild' button at playstore is disabled for now. It just keeps saying, Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy..

Comment: You will need to increment your version code, make a new APK and upload it again.

Comment: I have attached screen shot of the error message. Please check to see if you have any clue about it.

Comment: Ok i will try changing the version code and uploading apk again.